# Database structure. Transaction table handling multiple product ID's

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am currently developing a simple Point of Sale Android App. I have an Inventory table and a Transactions table. The Inventory table contains product information (PK)product_Id, product_name, price, and quantity. The Transactions table contains transaction information (PK)transaction_id, product_id, quantity, total_price. I would like the transaction table to be able to handle multiple product id's in one transaction. I don't know if I need to create another table or if it's possible to do it with just these two? Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant but in the Inventory table, the product quantity will be decremented based on the quantity ordered after a transaction.

Comment: You need to create another table.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a join table. You'll need a table that relates inventories with transactions. So, the table will contain foreign keys for them.

Let's say the table name is `inventories_transactions`
The columns in this table should be `id`, `inventory_id` & `transaction_id`, `quantity`, `total_price`

Your data should be like this.

Inventory table:

| id | product_id | product_name | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Dummy Product | 600 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2 | Dummy Product 2 | 500 | 2000 |

Transactions table:

| id | total_price | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 17000 | paid |

inventories_transactions table:

| id | inventory_id | transaction_id | amount | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20 | 12000 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 10 | 5000 |

On this example, a transaction has 2 products with ids 1 & 2. with individual total for both.

This creates a many to many relation between inventories and transactions. So, each transaction can contain many inventories. And each inventory can be used by multiple transactions.